# Issues when deploying Shiny app : Error in read.table

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

Although my app is working perfectly when I run it locally, I can't deploy it to shinyapps.io ! :(

Every single time I try, I get this annoying message:

> Warning message: Error detecting locale: Error in read.table(file =
>   file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : incomplete final
>   line found by readTableHeader on 'raw'  (Using default: en_US)

My scripts and my csv file are saved under the right encoding (UTF-8) and I've added an empty line to my csv (but I still get the following warning "incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'raw'"

Here is my code and my csv file:

ui:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(devtools)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(networkD3)
library(rsconnect)

communes <- readOGR("comm_etude_xl.shp")
tableau_excel <- read.csv("data_communes.csv", sep=";", encoding="UTF-8")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title ="Projet impermeabilite"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Contexte", tabName = "intro", icon = icon("info")),
      menuItem("Carte", tabName = "map", icon = icon("map")),
      menuItem("Donnees brutes", tabName = "tableau", icon = icon("table"))
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "map",
              fluidRow(
                valueBoxOutput("variable1"),#end box
                valueBoxOutput("variable2"),
                valueBoxOutput("variable3"),


                fluidRow(
                  box(height=450, status="primary", title="Carte", solidHeader=TRUE, collapsible=TRUE, leafletOutput(outputId = "mymap", height="380")),
                  box(height=450, status="warning", title="Graphique", solidHeader=TRUE, collapsible=TRUE, plotOutput(outputId = "myplot", height="380")
                  ))
              )),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "intro", h2("Contexte de l'etude")
      ),

      # Third tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "tableau",  h2("Tableau csv"), 
              fluidRow(
                DT::dataTableOutput("table")
              )
      ))
  ))
```

server:

```
server <- function(input, output){

  ## use reactive values to store the id from observing the shape click
  rv <- reactiveVal()

  output$mymap<-renderLeaflet(
    leaflet(communes) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
      setView(1.45, 43.52, zoom = 12) %>%
      addTiles()  %>% 
      addPolygons(fillColor = "blue",
                  weight = 2,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "white",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillOpacity = 0.3,
                  highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 5,
                    color = "#666",
                    dashArray = "",
                    fillOpacity = 0.7,
                    bringToFront = TRUE),
                  layerId = ~nm_cmmn)
  )

  observeEvent(input$mymap_shape_click, {
    rv(input$mymap_shape_click$id)
  })

  ## you can now 'output' your generated data however you want
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(rv())) return (NULL)
    tableau_excel %>%
      filter(nom_commune == rv()) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Variable"), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Variable, y = Value)) +
      geom_col() + ggtitle("Aide de prise a la decision dans la gestion des inondations") +
      xlab("SWI, TWI, densite de population") + ylab("Valeurs normalisees") + labs(fill="SWI, TWI, densite de population")
  })


  output$table<-DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(tableau_excel,
              class = 'cell-border stripe',
              editable = TRUE,
              options = list(scrollX = T))
  })

  output$variable1 <-renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "17.6%", "Pourcentage total de surfaces artificialisees sur la zone d'etude", icon = icon("building"),
      color = "red"
    )
  })

  output$variable2 <-renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "2147", "Nombre de personnes vivant dans la zone d'aleas inondation ", icon = icon("street-view"),
      color = "green"
    )
  })

  output$variable3 <-renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "4", "Nombre d'arretes de catastrophes naturelles sur la zone d'etude depuis 1983 ", icon = icon("cloud-showers-heavy"),
      color = "blue"
    )
  })


}

deployApp()
```

csv + shapefile:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wlSAwgz3TRATg2KoBEo9LVdkBmnFSKJ7

Many thanks in advance for your help !

**EDIT:**

```
> rsconnect::showLogs()
2020-03-02T12:45:44.844363+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.409910+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: â”€â”€ Attaching packages â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€ tidyverse 1.3.0 â”€â”€
2020-03-02T12:45:45.414479+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: âœ” ggplot2 3.2.1     âœ” purrr   0.3.3
2020-03-02T12:45:45.414480+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: âœ” tibble  2.1.3     âœ” stringr 1.4.0
2020-03-02T12:45:45.414481+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: âœ” tidyr   1.0.0     âœ” forcats 0.4.0
2020-03-02T12:45:45.414482+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: âœ” readr   1.3.1     
2020-03-02T12:45:45.554173+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: â”€â”€ Conflicts â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€ tidyverse_conflicts() â”€â”€
2020-03-02T12:45:45.554175+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: âœ– tidyr::extract()   masks raster::extract(), magrittr::extract()
2020-03-02T12:45:45.571473+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     dataTableOutput, renderDataTable
2020-03-02T12:45:45.554176+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: âœ– dplyr::filter()    masks stats::filter()
2020-03-02T12:45:45.571474+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.571107+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.571471+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: The following objects are masked from â€˜package:shinyâ€™:
2020-03-02T12:45:45.613669+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.571472+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.613967+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: The following object is masked from â€˜package:leafletâ€™:
2020-03-02T12:45:45.554177+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: âœ– dplyr::lag()       masks stats::lag()
2020-03-02T12:45:45.613306+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.613968+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.554178+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: âœ– purrr::set_names() masks magrittr::set_names()
2020-03-02T12:45:45.613309+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.624899+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: Attaching package: â€˜rsconnectâ€™
2020-03-02T12:45:45.634453+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.554177+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: âœ– raster::select()   masks dplyr::select()
2020-03-02T12:45:45.613308+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: Attaching package: â€˜networkD3â€™
2020-03-02T12:45:45.624897+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.625531+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.571097+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.613667+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: The following object is masked from â€˜package:DTâ€™:
2020-03-02T12:45:45.624899+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.634465+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: Source: "/srv/connect/apps/rshiny/comm_etude_xl.shp", layer: "comm_etude_xl"
2020-03-02T12:45:45.571106+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: Attaching package: â€˜DTâ€™
2020-03-02T12:45:45.613668+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.625225+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: The following object is masked from â€˜package:devtoolsâ€™:
2020-03-02T12:45:45.634480+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: with 11 features
2020-03-02T12:45:45.613669+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     JS
2020-03-02T12:45:45.625225+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.634487+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: It has 6 fields
2020-03-02T12:45:45.625226+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     lint
2020-03-02T12:45:45.625226+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.613967+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.613968+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     JS
2020-03-02T12:45:45.625530+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T12:45:45.625530+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: The following object is masked from â€˜package:shinyâ€™:
2020-03-02T12:45:45.625531+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     serverInfo
2020-03-02T12:45:48.398235+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: Warning: Error in : You must register an account using setAccountInfo prior to proceeding.
2020-03-02T12:45:48.401925+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   67: stop
2020-03-02T12:45:48.401926+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   66: stopWithNoAccount
2020-03-02T12:45:48.401927+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   65: deploymentTarget
2020-03-02T12:45:48.401927+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   64: deployApp
2020-03-02T12:45:48.402019+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: Error : You must register an account using setAccountInfo prior to proceeding.
```

**EDIT 2:***

```
> rsconnect::showLogs()
2020-03-02T13:19:09.176637+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T13:19:09.176639+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T13:19:09.176967+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: The following object is masked from â€˜package:devtoolsâ€™:
2020-03-02T13:19:09.176968+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T13:19:09.176969+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     lint
2020-03-02T13:19:09.186971+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
2020-03-02T13:19:09.176969+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T13:19:09.177268+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: The following object is masked from â€˜package:shinyâ€™:
2020-03-02T13:19:09.177269+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T13:19:09.177270+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     serverInfo
2020-03-02T13:19:09.177270+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: 
2020-03-02T13:19:09.186988+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: Source: "/srv/connect/apps/rshiny/comm_etude_xl.shp", layer: "comm_etude_xl"
2020-03-02T13:19:09.186989+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: with 11 features
2020-03-02T13:19:09.187010+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: It has 6 fields
2020-03-02T13:19:14.115280+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: Warning: Error in structure: object 'communes' not found
2020-03-02T13:19:14.120848+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   114: structure
2020-03-02T13:19:14.120852+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     6: eval
2020-03-02T13:19:14.120849+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   111: leaflet
2020-03-02T13:19:14.120850+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   107: func
2020-03-02T13:19:14.120851+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    94: origRenderFunc
2020-03-02T13:19:14.120851+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    13: runApp
2020-03-02T13:19:14.120852+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    12: fn
2020-03-02T13:19:14.120851+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    93: output$mymap
2020-03-02T13:19:14.120852+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     7: connect$retry
2020-03-02T13:19:14.120852+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     5: eval
2020-03-02T13:20:56.884363+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: Warning: Error in structure: object 'communes' not found
2020-03-02T13:20:56.887735+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   114: structure
2020-03-02T13:20:56.887737+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   111: leaflet
2020-03-02T13:20:56.887738+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    94: origRenderFunc
2020-03-02T13:20:56.887769+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     5: eval
2020-03-02T13:20:56.887738+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    93: output$mymap
2020-03-02T13:20:56.887739+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    12: fn
2020-03-02T13:20:56.887739+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     7: connect$retry
2020-03-02T13:20:56.887739+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     6: eval
2020-03-02T13:20:56.887737+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   107: func
2020-03-02T13:20:56.887738+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    13: runApp
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764571+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   116: crosstalk::is.SharedData
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764585+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     7: connect$retry
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764572+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   115: datatable
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764585+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     6: eval
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764574+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   112: func
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764573+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   114: exprFunc [/srv/connect/apps/rshiny/server.R#44]
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764586+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:     5: eval
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764584+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    93: output$table
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764573+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:   113: widgetFunc
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764574+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    99: origRenderFunc
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764584+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    94: origRenderFunc
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764584+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    98: renderFunc
2020-03-02T13:20:59.760900+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]: Warning: Error in crosstalk::is.SharedData: object 'tableau_excel' not found
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764585+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    13: runApp
2020-03-02T13:20:59.764585+00:00 shinyapps[1888035]:    12: fn
```

Comment: are you confident that it isn't starting?
my apps works after this warning

Comment: https://wanderzen.shinyapps.io/rshiny/

It's "kind of" deployed but it is not working ! :/

Comment: send logs from admin menu pls

Comment: I've edited my post so you can see the logs.

Comment: I don't understand the last line (Error : You must register an account using setAccountInfo prior to proceeding) since I've provided all the informations needed in my script with "rsconnect" !

Comment: remove  `deployApp()` from server.R

Comment: Ok but where should I put it then ?

Comment: nothing, just replace `server <- function(input, output)` to  `shinyServer <- shiny::shinyServer(function(input, output, session)`

Comment: Ok so it has definitely changed something since now we can see the app: https://wanderzen.shinyapps.io/rshiny/

Comment: But I still can't see my map nor the dataframe. I've edited again my post with the new log details. It says it cannot find my shapefile and my csv even though they are integrated in the ui script

Comment: read it inside server.R

Comment: Damn it worked !!! Thank you so much jyjek ! I was not taught to deploy a shiny app like that but your method is definetly better !!! Thanks again !! Maybe you could copy and paste all your comments in an aswer to my post so I can update this topic as solved ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have trailing semicolons in your data and header.

```
nom_commune;code_insee;population;TWI;Variable_densite;Variable_SWI_moyen;Variable_TWI_moyen;
PORTET-SUR-GARONNE;31433;9836;13.776;2.77782654494382;5.7465495608532;10;;
```

Several of your lines ends with a semicolon, which might cause trouble with your import. Try removing these, and see if it helps.